# Executing shell command from MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I know what I'm looking for is probably a security hole, but since I managed to do it in Oracle and SQL Server, I'll give it a shot:

I'm looking for a way to execute a shell command from a SQL script on MySQL. It is possible to create and use a new stored procedure if necessary.

Notice: I'm not looking for the SYSTEM command which the mysql command line tool offers. Instead I'm looking for something like this:

> BEGIN   IF
>   COND1...
>       EXEC_OS cmd1;   ELSE
>       EXEC_OS cmd2; END;

where EXEC_OS is the method to invocate my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider writing your scripts in a more featureful scripting language, like Perl, Python, PHP, or Ruby.  All of these languages have libraries to run SQL queries.

There is no built-in method in the stored procedure language for running shell commands.  This is considered a bad idea, not only because it's a security hole, but because any effects of shell commands do not obey transaction isolation or rollback, as do the effects of any SQL operations you do in the stored procedure:

```
START TRANSACTION;
CALL MyProcedure();
ROLLBACK;
```

If `MyProcedure` did anything like create or edit a file, or send an email, etc., those operations would not roll back.

I would recommend doing your SQL work in the stored procedure, and do other work in the application that calls the stored procedure.

Comment: That's a bogus academic argument! A lot of real-world problems do not require rollback capability. And a lot of real-world problems could use the type of event-driven processing that would be enabled by such a feature.

Comment: @Alex R: It's a moot point, since MySQL stored procedures don't support running a shell command anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't so much an answer to the question as it is justification for this sort of functionality - hence negating those who would say "you should do something else" or "why would you want to".

I have a database which I am trying to keep strict rules on - I don't want orphans anywhere. Referential integrity checks help me with this on the table level, but I have to keep some of the data as files within the filesystem (this is a result from a direct order from my boss to not store any binary data in the database itself).

The obvious solution here is to have a trigger which fires on deletion of a record, which then automatically deletes the associated external file.

Now, I do realise that UDF's may provide a solution, but that seems like a lot of C/C++ work to simply delete a file. Surely the database permissions themselves would provide at least **some** security from would-be assailants.

Now, I do realise that I could write a shell script or some such which could delete the table record and then go and delete the related file, but again, that's outside the domain of the database *itself*. As an old instructor once told me "the rules of the business should be reflected in the rules of the database". As one can clearly see, I cannot enforce this using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

see do_system() in http://www.databasesecurity.com/mysql/HackproofingMySQL.pdf

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,198595,198899#msg-198899) at the forums.mysql.com, the solution is to use the [MySQL_Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy).