# Put trigger in MySQL database to update Oracle database?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, triggers

I want to create an insert trigger on MySQL which will automatically insert the record into an Oracle database. I would like to know if there are people that have experience to share on this topic.

Cheers

Comment: I doubt this would ever work - mysql knows nothing about oracle and vice versa

Comment: Thank you Adrian. Do you have any recommendation about synchronizing data across these two different databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Invoke a script as is done in this example](http://www.boosten.org/2009/using-triggers-in-mysql/) that calls the Oracle code.

Note: you lose support for transactions (there will be no built-in rollback for the Oracle database) when you perform this type of cascading, and you also will take a likely very large performance hit in doing so. The script could turn around and simply call Java code or some other executable that invokes your some generic code to insert into Oracle, or it could be a raw query that gets passed arguments from the script.

This is almost certainly a bad idea because of the odd side-effect behavior, but it's one that can be implemented. I think that you would be much better off having the code to do this against two different `DataSource`s (in Java/.NET speak) rather than have a hidden script in a MySQL trigger that screams unmaintainable, as well as hidden failure for future developers.

Comment: You can get a trigger to call a script - did not know that

Comment: I think it only really makes sense in rare, kick-off-some-process circumstances like the one in the example (processing on the first of the month). Beyond that, I think the opportunity for abuse may exceed the value of it.

Comment: Especially since mysql now has an event scheduler

Comment: You are right pickypg. This issue I'm worrying is the possible hidden failure. But because the update of the Mysql database is conducted only by one end user, there will be less performance issues.

In addition, the example script you provided is for Mysql, not for Oracle. I will be appreciate if you could provide an Oracle example.

Comment: @sounder The easiest way would be to install lib_mysql_udfsys (noting its words of caution), and then literally invoking a bash script that logs into Oracle and then executes the `INSERT` command via the trigger as a function call like `CALL sys_eval('/path/to/script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3', sysout_of_oracle)`.

Comment: I still think that the easier--and safer--solution might be to create a process for your users that has them manually call MySQL, which internally then invokes Oracle upon success. It will be a bit less voodoo for future developers, and you will know if it fails. Of interest, if you took the time, you could actually cause your trigger in the above to do a rollback based on the system out printed from Oracle, but in a far more verbose manner than done through code.

Comment: You can also compile in C/C++ code as [library functions here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html). From the code you can very quickly invoke whatever you want, and add or drop it as you please while adding [privileged access only to accounts that deserve it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html). The simplest library implementation that I've seen is [here](http://www.databasesecurity.com/mysql/HackproofingMySQL.pdf) (see `do_system`) from this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/289952/706724).