# how to run the python script from the mysql query?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a desire to call the python script from the mysql query.

like we call the procedure in mysql : call procedurename();

just like as above is there any way in mysql to call external scripts like ,

```
                       call script(somefile.py)
```

i wrote the above thing to explain the exactly what i want.

Comment: What would be the use case for this? This is crossing domains that in my opinion shouldn't be crossed.

Comment: there is a event_shceduler in mysql by useing that i want run event_shcduler in mysql periodically along with calling the external scripts ,
Even i know cron job in linux and winwods scheduler ,

Answer (score 4):

This does not seem to be possible in MySQL, for security reasons. You can have a look at this related question [Executing shell command from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/289914/1699750). You can however do this in other database like oracle. In Postgresql there is also support to create [python stored procedures in the database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpython.html). You could use this technique to have your database triggers run python code.