# Error running python script with mysql trigger

Tags: python, mysql, triggers, permissions, logfiles

I want to run a python script using a trigger defined in mysql. I'm using the following:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER T
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd = CONCAT('python /home/trigger.py');
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END;
$
DELIMITER ;
```

But it seems that mysql can not run the python script. I'm getting the following error in the log file:

> [21567.146058] type=1400 audit(1398864654.174:68): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" parent=3054 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/bin/dash" pid=5011 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=116 ouid=0

Can any one help please?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run the python script from the mysql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729594/how-to-run-the-python-script-from-the-mysql-query)

Comment: No It's different. Here I'm having problems with permissions since mysql can not run the script while it is possible.