# Call Python Function Within SQL Query In MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a python script which I would like to call from within a SQL SELECT statement in MySQL.

```
SELECT myPythonFunc([column_name])
FROM someTable
```

I am able to do this in oracle DB with jar files (loadjava).  Is there a way to do this with Python scripts in MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: you need to return the data into python first, then you can run a calculation

Comment: You can define a method in MySQL using `CREATE FUNCTION` but you can not run python method on SQL statement as far as I know but you can try `PostgreSQL.` . Also take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729594/how-to-run-the-python-script-from-the-mysql-query

Comment: @dataviews do you mean get the query results first and then pass them into the python function?

Comment: @webDev very useful, thank you

Comment: @user1239i2304 exactly. You could also use the create function within mysql, but if you are working with the data in python, it may be more efficient (less load on the data base) to handle your analysis.

Comment: Hey, did you find out a way to run python function within MySQL?